# Services in angularJS not working in controller

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I have easy service in my app.

```
var app = angular.module("appTest", []);
app.service('AuthService', function ($scope) {
$scope.write = function(){
    console.log("service")
};
});
```

And I want to use it in my controller

```
var app = angular.module('appTest');
app.controller("LoginController", ['$scope', '$http', '$cookies', 
'$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$location',
function ($scope, $http, $cookies, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $location, 
AuthService) {

AuthService.write();

}]);
```

But I have mistake http://prntscr.com/mckff7

I did my service by any case. Result the same.

I add my service by this way http://prntscr.com/mckgrt

Answer (score 2):

You're not 'injecting' the AuthService into your controller. You're receiving it as an object, but you need to declare it in the array of strings too for it to actually be injected.

Your controller code should look like this:

```
var app = angular.module('appTest', []);

app.service('AuthService', function ($scope) {
  $scope.write = function(){
        console.log('hello world');
  };
});

app.controller("LoginController", ['$scope', '$http', '$cookies', 
    '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$location', 'AuthService',
    function ($scope, $http, $cookies, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $location, 
    AuthService) {

        AuthService.write();

}]);
```

Comment: That's not the same result, it's a different error. It's because i didn't copy the code for the `AuthService` controller, so it wasn't defined. I created a working jsfiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/e4k9sy31/4/

Comment: Also fixed my code in the answer, to be a full working example

Comment: The same result. I added angularJS old version and the result the same.  I create the new simple project on .net core anf try to call service on app.run. Here the link.  If you can to see it will be cool! Thanks! https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Dg8zcGEySUU8UbsL339B-gZgr7QrsNDF

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to download a 'rar' file and try to run it locally - Regardless, the .net code has nothing to do with this. Try extracting the relevant parts of your code to a "jsfiddle" (like i did), and then I might be able to help you understand where your problem is.